Is there a term for this academic writing issue?
I'm new at reviewing articles to be published in an academic journal. In one journal I'm reviewing, the author repeated these phrases around 20 times: Students need..., Educators need to..., Teachers need to..., etc. I don't know what this is called, but it does come across as preachy. I need to give good feedback and it would help to know what it's called. Thanks!

It’s unclear whether this is part of what you are objecting to, but many times when an author writes, “X needs to…,” what is really the case is “I need X to…”  Sentences like Inflation needs to fall before the Federal Reserve will act are, technically, nonsensical because inflation doesn’t—or I should write can’t —need anything. So perhaps some of your discomfort with the paper isn’t so much its overuse of need but its misuse?

If there is a name for it and you don't know it, it is likely your author doesn't know it either and will only be mystified by some obscure technical term.
I would simply call this "repetitive" and explain why it seems preachy to you.

In text linguistics, the technical term for the functional repetition of words or phrases is recurrence. The function of recurrence is to provide cohesion.
It could be argued that the recurring use of "students/teachers need to" is indeed functional in the text of your author. It alerts the reader that a recommendation is following, much like the icons such as raised fingers in some textbooks, and it may be one aim of the text (at least in the mind of its author) to recommend a certain practice.
Rephrasing these repetitive phrases to something more varied and less prescriptive might read better, though, for example "You might want to...", "We recommend that...", "Conventionally...", and so on.

It's called, "Show, not tell."
In school, I was taught that for research articles, you should stay away from using "you" and go more to "they," "he," "she," etc. Also, stay away from "you need to do this," or "teachers need to do this." Let it speak for itself. Example:
Instead of: "Teachers need to listen to students to make students perform better
Do: "According to research, teachers who listen to students end up having better student performance overall" (provide evidence afterwards)
Let the research speak for itself, instead of telling them what it is directly. Let them lean in by showing them the answers. Solve the question with proof, not a "tell" answer.

I'm not sure this strictly answers the question, which is about whether there's a term for this particular issue, rather than how to fix it.

@F1Krazy I added something at the beginning. Does that work?

I believe so, yes. Thank you.
